# Creating a Custom Conditional TagLib in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, taglib

I am trying to create a conditional taglib in grails to determine whether or not to display a user Avatar (I based the code on the ifLoggedIn tags found here: http://www.grails.org/AuthTagLib )

My taglib looks like this:

```
def ifProfileAvatar = {attrs, body ->
  def username = session.user.login
  def currentUser = Account.findByLogin(username)
  if (currentUser.profile && currentUser.profile.avatar) {
    out << "avatar found"
    body{}
  }
}
```

And in my GSP I use the tag like this:

```
<g:ifProfileAvatar>
<br/>profile found!<br/>
</g:ifProfileAvatar>
```

When I navigate to the GSP, "avatar found" is being displayed correctly (directly from the taglib) but "profile found!" is not.

Is there any reason that the `body{}` in the taglib is not showing the body in the GSP?

Any ideas where it might be going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrong sort of braces after `body`, I think it should be:

```
def ifProfileAvatar = {attrs, body ->
  def username = session.user.login
  def currentUser = Account.findByLogin(username)
  if (currentUser.profile && currentUser.profile.avatar) {
    out << "avatar found"
    out << body() // Use () not {}
  }
}
```

See [this page in the documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#logicalTags) for more examples

Comment: Perfect! I was missing the correct braces and the out<< bit!  all workign great now